# Return records where other fields are blank

Tags: ms-access

I have an access query that returns the following records;

```
Customer             Invoiced         The Plan Value        Sales
Cust1                 22110 
Cust2           
Cust3                                      14143            5391
Cust4           
Cust5           
Cust6           
Cust7                341648 
Cust8                43910                                 123309
Cust9                32096                 288403
```

I want to be able to run a query that will return customer where at least one of the fields Invoiced, The Plan Value, Sales and not return records where they are all blank.

My expected results would be;

```
Customer             Invoiced         The Plan Value        Sales
Cust1                 22110 
Cust3                                      14143            5391            
Cust7                341648 
Cust8                43910                                 123309
Cust9                32096                 288403
```

My Current Query is;

```
SELECT qry_Final_output.Customer, 
       qry_Final_output.Invoiced, 
       qry_Final_output.[The Plan Value], 
       qry_Final_output.Sales
FROM qry_Final_output;
```

Comment: Show us the query, please.

Comment: I've updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` clause and check whether the fields are `NULL`:

```
SELECT qry_Final_output.Customer, 
       qry_Final_output.Invoiced, 
       qry_Final_output.[The Plan Value], 
       qry_Final_output.Sales 
FROM qry_Final_output
WHERE qry_Final_output.Invoiced IS NOT NULL
   OR qry_Final_output.[The Plan Value] IS NOT NULL
   OR qry_Final_output.Sales IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: This just returns records where all fields have a value. This is not what I want. I need it to return records where at least 1 of the fields has a value.

Comment: Thanks,now when running the query, it comes up saying - Enter Parameter Value: qry_Final_output